# Problems with setting Headers in Artemis Webconsole

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am having trouble with setting headers in the web console of Artemis. If I try to add a header field I can write the write in the header name and the value in the appearing text boxes, but if I press "Send message" nothing happens and an error is printed to the built-in error console.

```
[ARTEMIS] 123 
[ARTEMIS] About to send headers: {"JMSPriority":"4"}
[ARTEMIS] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Core] Operation sendMessage(java.util.Map, int, java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) failed due to: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

This happens when I am trying to use predefined headers like "JMSPriority" aswell as custom header fields.

The funny thing is that I if set the header fields in a Java application I can use the predefined headers aswell as custom headers without any problems.

Is there a special way to add (custom) header fields to messages in the Artemis web console?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a [server issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2332) and it should be fixed in the last versions

Answer (score 0):

The body must be base64 encoded:

[image]